# Problems with the whitelist of an addon

Tags: google-apps-script

I am developing an addon for gmail, in this I need to make calls to an api hosted on a server, the problem arises in that I can only add urls to the whitelist of the addon if they are HTTPS, and the query that I need to do has the following format

HTTP://example/:8080/example/oslc/am/cf/resource/

Is there any way to add http queries to the whitelist? or any other way to make them?

Comment: which whitelist do you mean exactly?

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk OP is referring to the URL whitelist in the manifest (appsscript.json).

HTTPS is required. If possible contact the owner of the site and ask them to upgrade to HTTPS.